How to best add the Last-Modified header in asp .net middleware
Is there a way of adding the Last-Modified header to an API response in asp .net?
Perhaps a "best practice"?
I'm reading a date with "last modified" from the database, and would like to set that in the header so that resources can cache accordingly.
I guess I don't know enough about the life cycle of the response.
Is there an event I can attach to where I have access to both the response (headers) and before the result object is serialized to JSON ?
 app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {                
            context.Response.OnStarting(() =>
            {
                 // context.Response.Body seams to already have been set to a 
                 // stream object, and I would in stead like to find the date in 
                 // the object I'm sending back, which implements an interface 
                 // containing the date
                 context.Response.Headers.Append("Last-Modified","????");
            }
        })

The code in the API controller
[HttpGet]
    [Route("system/resources/{lcid}")]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]        
    public async Task<IResult> Get(int lcid, CancellationToken token)
    {            
        var resources = (await _resourceManager.GetResourcesAsync(lcid, token).ConfigureAwait(false));


        if (resources?.Items?.Any() ?? false)
        {                
            // resources has a .LastModified property
            return Results.Ok(resources );
        }
        else
        {
            return Results.NotFound();
        }

    }

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Last-Modified

Just a thought: you can probably use context to retrieve a custom service that would store any data you store in it, conveniently request-scoped.

How is the data returned now? Why not set the header in the action or API handler? You need access to the database data to set the header. FileResult already has LastModified. For other results you can use Response.Headers.LastModified

@PanagiotisKanavos Ah, off course. Feel stupid now :-( Don't vote me down

You should still post the code. If you need the same functionality in multiple places some kind of middleware would make sense, just not a generic middleware. Perhaps Filters? The Middleware Order diagrams show that action filters are the closest to user code

@PanagiotisKanavos Sure. I have added now. If you make a reply post, I'll mark it "Answered"

@PanagiotisKanavos Perhaps I was a bit too quick. This section never hits:
if (context.Result is OkObjectResult { Value: ICacheInfo c })
I have set the interface on the object, but it never returns true and never enters the if block

The easiest way is to just set the header in the action itself :
   if (resources?.Items?.Any() ?? false)
    {                
        Response.Headers.LastModified=resources.LastModified;
        // resources has a .LastModified property
        return Results.Ok(resources );
    }
    else
    {
        return Results.NotFound();
    }

A reusable option could be to create an action filter. Let's assume the result implements this ICacheInfo interface so we don't have to use reflection. It uses a default interface member so it can be applied to objects and modified without breaking the object :
interface ICacheInfo
{
    DateTimeOffset LastModified=>DateTimeOffset.Now;
}

The action filter could look like this:
public class LastModifiedHeaderAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (context.Result is OkObjectResult {Value:ICacheInfo c})
        {
            context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.LastModified=c.LastModified;
        }

        base.OnResultExecuting(context);
    }
}

And applied as an attribute:
[HttpGet]
[Route("system/resources/{lcid}")]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]        
[LastModifiedHeader]
public async Task<IResult> Get(int lcid, CancellationToken token)
{  
...
}

